# Enable ThinkPad Trackpad on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, x11, touchpad, thinkpad, xinput

I'm using Arch Linux on a Lenovo ThinkPad P14s. On a fresh install, the trackpad is disabled.

It's cumbersome to carry a mouse wherever I go, and the red knob in the middle of the keyboard is far from ideal for mouse movement.

How do I enable the trackpad?

Here is my `xinput list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                    id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated I           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I've performed `xinput set-prop # "Device Enabled" 1` for every id on the list.

Edit: It appears `lsusb` does not show the touchpad. Here is the output of `lsusb`:

````
Bus 006 Device 004: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. AX200 Bluetooth
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc. Prometheus MIS Touch Fingerprint Reader
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b6d0 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub```
````

Answer (score 1):

Described in the Arch Linux Wiki: [Touchpad Synaptics](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Configuration)

Install the `xf86-input-synaptics` package:

```
sudo pacman -S xf86-input-synaptics
```

Then create the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf` with the following content:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        Option "TapButton1" "1"
        Option "TapButton2" "3"
        Option "TapButton3" "2"
        Option "VertEdgeScroll" "on"
        Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "on"
        Option "HorizEdgeScroll" "on"
        Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "on"
        Option "CircularScrolling" "on"
        Option "CircScrollTrigger" "2"
        Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinZ" "40"
        Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinW" "8"
        Option "CoastingSpeed" "0"
        Option "FingerLow" "30"
        Option "FingerHigh" "50"
        Option "MaxTapTime" "125"
        ...
EndSection
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. Unfortunately this does not work. I've updated my question to reflect that it appears my `lsusb` does not list the touchpad, if this offers any insight into what the problem may be.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by rebooting into Windows, then back into Arch Linux. This seems to be a solution that will fix the problem every time it occurs; I will update my answer if this turns out not to be the case.